# Random audio with title on-screen

Tags: javascript, audio

I'm trying to do loading screen (idk JS) that will play a random sound file (selected from an array), files (.ogg) are hosted on the local server, and display the title at the screen. 
And here is the question, how to do it.

Comment: What are your research efforts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your question is not so clear but for doing this you have two ways :

1.front side rendering with javascript frame works and make a random number (consider you have 3 audio files) like this : 

`var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
var audioArray = ['track1','track2','track3'];`

and after every time reloading you can change your audio like this :

`audioArray[random]` on jquery or javascript

2.server side rendering

Comment: `var BGM = [];
BGM[0] = "6.ogg";
BGM[1] = "6.ogg";
BGM[2] = "6.ogg";
BGM[3] = "6.ogg";
BGM[4] = "6.ogg";
BGM[5] = "6.ogg";

var idx = Math.round( Math.random() * 5 );

document.write('<audio autoplay loop> <source src='"+BGM[idx]+"' type="audio/ogg">'); 
if  (idx == 0)
document.write('<h1>test0</h1>')
else if (idx == 1)
document.write('<h1>test1</h1>')
else if (idx == 2)
document.write('<h1>test2</h1>')
else if (idx == 3)
document.write('<h1>test3</h1>')
else if (idx == 4)
document.write('<h1>test4</h1>')
else
document.write('<h1>test5</h1>')`

what's wrong?

Comment: `var BGM = [];
BGM[0] = "6.ogg";
var idx = Math.round( Math.random() * 5 );
document.write('<audio autoplay loop> <source src='"+BGM[idx]+"' type="audio/ogg">');
if  (idx == 0)
document.write('<h1>test0</h1>')`

Comment: It doesn't work.
The music doesn't play and test(number) does not show up

Comment: i dont understand how this JS code works. I'm not good at javascript

Comment: I've finally fixed the code! 
`if (idx == 1)
document.write('<h1>test1</h1>');
document.write('<audio autoplay loop> <source src='+BGM[idx]+' type="audio/ogg">');`
that helped me
thanks for help!!

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.

Answer (score 0):

this is for jquery :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).load(function() {
  var data = ['path/to/track1','path/to/track2','path/to/track3','path/to/track4','path/to/track5'];
  var idx = Math.round( Math.random() * 5 ); 
      $(".audio").replaceWith( "<audio class='audio' controls loop><source src='" + data[idx] + " 'type='audio/ogg'></audio>" );
  });
});
```

and this for your html :

```
<audio class="audio" controls loop>
  <source src="horse.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
  <source src="horse.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```